# How to restrict duplicate data entry

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2010

I wish to create condition formatting for my customer:

This will be my data:

```
     A           B
1: Name Ticket Number
2: Jack         123
3: Jack         123
4: Jack         123
5: Kimberly     456
6: Kimberly     123
7: Kimberly     456
8: Kurt         456
9: Kurt         587
10: Jack        123
```

I wish to create a condition formatting for the specific customer called Jack.

For example,

1. If Ticket number for Jack will be 123, than the ticket number cannot be repeated on others customer. If others customer are using the same ticket number, than the customer named will be highlighted.
2. For others customer, Kurt and Kimberly or others new entry customer, they ticket number can be use repeatedly.
3. The ticket number shall not repeat again once the specific customer Jack have appear on the top. For example in B10, the the ticket number should be key in with other number that is not same as the top Jack's ticket number and others customer ticket number. It should be a unique number like 789. If it repeat, the cell will be highlighted.

Here will be the example that I wish it to look like :

```
     A           B
1: Name Ticket Number
2: Jack         123      -> will not be highlighted
3: Jack         123      -> will not be highlighted
4: Jack         123      -> will not be highlighted
5: Kimberly     456      -> will not be highlighted because it doesn't contain the same ticket number with Jack|123
6: Kimberly     123      -> this will be highlighted because it contain same ticket number with Jack|123 
7: Kimberly     456      -> will not be highlighted because it doesn't contain the same ticket number with Jack|123 
8: Kurt         456      -> will not be highlighted because it doesn't contain the same ticket number with Jack|123 and Kurt can share the same ticket number with Kimberly or others customers besides than Jack
9: Kurt         587      -> will not be highlighted because it doesn't contain the same ticket number with Jack|123 
10: Jack        123      -> will be highlighted because ticket number 123 is appear on the top of the list(B2:B4), it should contain a new ticket number after few customer have being insert after Jack on B2:B4
11: Jack        789      -> will not be highlighted because it doesn't contain the same ticket number with Jack on B2:B4 after few customer being insert in the middle and ticket number 789 is different with others customer as well.
```

Thank you.

Comment: no.1 and 2 is ok. But I'm not sure with no.3.

Answer (score 0):

As commented, below formula will highlight any customer that share any ticket number Jack holds.

```
=IF($A2<>"JACK",IF(ISERROR(MATCH($B2,IF($A$2:A$11="JACK",$B$2:B$11,""),0)),FALSE,TRUE))
```

Comment: @pnuts On his first post I think I read he/she wants to highlight the name. But anyways, my answer only partially meets the OP's requirement. So this does not really fully answer the question. I just post it in case the OP needs it:). If a complete answer came, I'd just delete it. :)